# Unable to find a suitable output format for 'ffmpeg' android

Tags: android, ffmpeg

I want to overlay two video using FFMPEG. I´m using the executable/binary file of ffmpeg and I´m calling my ffmpeg commands like that:

```
String[] complexCommand = {"ffmpeg", "-i", yourRealPath, "-vf", "movie="+yourRealPath+ "[a];movie="+compare_moviePath +"[b]; [in][a] overlay=0:366 [c]; [c][b] overlay=592:41", filePath};
```

But when I try this command I get this error:

```
Unable to find a suitable output format for 'ffmpeg'
```

Comment: This occurs when you have "ffmpeg" twice in your command, as in `ffmpeg ffmpeg -i input.mp4 output.mp4`. Remove `"ffmpeg", ` and try again.

Comment: Also, but not related to the issue, no need for movie filter. Just declare the overlay  inputs normally: `ffmpeg -i input0 -i input1 -i input2 -filter_complex "[0][1]overlay[bg];[bg][2]overlay" output`

Answer (score 2):

This Error says that ffmpeg is not supported output format. because when command pass to ffmpeg binary it will be

```
ffmpeg ffmpeg -i 1.mp4 -vf movie=2.mp4[a];movie=3.mp4[b];[in][a] overlay=0:366 [c]; [c][b] overlay=592:41 output.mp4
```

so binary can not find FFMPEG as supported format

so just remove that 'ffmpeg' from Array it will works fine

your array should be

```
String[] complexCommand = {"-i", yourRealPath, "-vf", "movie="+yourRealPath+ "[a];movie="+compare_moviePath +"[b]; [in][a] overlay=0:366 [c]; [c][b] overlay=592:41", filePath};
```